# Orientdb 2.2.2 "create user" in distributed setup returns ODistributedOperationException

Tags: orientdb, createuser

Is the "create user" command supported in a distributed setup (version 2.2.2)?  Any time I use it, I get a distributed operation exception (screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nd9m52i8dbk7r4t/Screenshot%202016-06-15%2010.51.13.png?dl=0)

It seems that the entry is created in both servers, just with a different password hash which collides.  Screenshot of user creation process (redacted) https://www.dropbox.com/s/r4oywkc5gqj6lsj/Screenshot%202016-06-15%2012.26.04.png?dl=0 and https://www.dropbox.com/s/2poi06z9mxxqr26/Screenshot%202016-06-15%2012.26.43.png?dl=0

Strangely, if I run the command on devgro1, I can login using the credentials on the OTHER server (devgro2), but not on the server I ran the command on.

To add to the confusion, I can't use the old method of inserting into OUser either:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ruxes4vkop4kigb/Screenshot%202016-06-15%2012.19.30.png?dl=0

Comment: Hi @Justin Did one of the server, or both, went in timeout because of inactivity?

Comment: No, they are both active and talking, and they both create a record in the OUser table, just with different hashes

Comment: Moved to GitHub: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6307

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a bug in version 2.2.2.  Recommended action is to revert to the 2.1.x versions that doesn't have this bug, or upgrade to one where it is fixed (not available as of the time of this post, but might be for an future readers).